# Can Someone help me? Is there a way to find out the area and circumference using only the given lengths?

Tags: geometry

Consider the circle below and all of its markings and then answer the following questions.

[image: Two intersecting chords in a circle]

a. What is the area and circumference of circle

b. If the arc measure of arc cod is 100 degrees and the arc measure of arc bsa is 60, what is the angle measure of angle crb?

Comment: You did not transcribed question (b) properly. Also, what have you tried so far?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics SE! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). For equations, please refer to this [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Don't use links as the main content of your post. This makes your question impossible to search.

Comment: i have tried the formula s = (0/360)*C but i don't know what to put in for the variables. As for question b, the question is written exactly the same. Ignore the previous statement.

Comment: Is $P$ known to be the center of the circle?

Comment: Hint: [Intersecting chords theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersecting_chords_theorem)

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

(a) You can use the power of a point, or the fact that $\triangle RAB\sim\triangle RDC$.

(b) If $P$ is the centre of the circle, 
$\angle CBD=\angle CPD\div 2$ and $\angle ACB=\angle APB\div 2$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint.-$\overline{RD}=\dfrac{4\cdot4,5}{3}=6$ so the radio is equal to $r=\dfrac{6+3}{2}=\dfrac92$. This gives the area and circumference of circle.

The arc formed by an angle $\theta$ (mesured in radians) is given by arc$=r\theta$ and $1^{\circ}=\dfrac{\pi}{180}$ radians so you can transforme the angles.